# Magento Generic Collection

Tags: magento

I have a model and I want to use a collection to hold these object as opposed to just an array.  I am wondering whether i need to create my own collection class or if there is a generic collection class i can use instead.

Is this possible in Magento?

Answer (score 0):

For collection work you will need in order:

yourmodel/Model/Mysql4/Youmodel/Collection.php extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract.
With this: `protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('modelname/model');
    }`
yourmodel/Model/Mysql4/Setup.php extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup.
And something like that in your config.xml

```
        <models>
        <you_model_name>
            <class>you_model_name_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>you_model_name_mysql4</resourceModel>
                    </you_model_name>
                    <you_model_name_mysql4>
                        <class>you_model_name_Model_Mysql4</class>
                        <entities>
                            <you_model_name><table>you_model_name</table></you_model_name>
                        </entities>
                    </you_model_name_mysql4>
    </you_model_name>
```

Now just call:

```
Mage::getModel('yourmodel/yourmodel')->getCollection();
```

Comment: Setup class is not necessary, certainly not EAV setup class if the entity is non-EAV. No harm though.

Comment: this is what i was trying to avoid.  I was looking for a way to have generic empty collection where i can use addItem to add my items to.  Its used in only one small part of code